# Problem in aligning the test data with the training data when developing a text analysis model

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I am following a tutorial on YouTube to learn about text analysis.

So far, we've developed a model that aims to predict if a SMS message is ham or spam.

Now, the tutor is preparing the test data so that it matches the format of the training data. This involves performing identical preprocessing steps on the test data, including tokenization, incorporating bigrams, and converting it into a Document-Feature Matrix (DFM).

But here, in this last line of code of this process, I get an error (the tutorial was published 5 years ago):

```
test.tokens.dfm <- dfm_select(test.tokens.dfm, 
                              pattern = train.tokens.dfm,
                              selection = "keep")
```

Alternatively, he provided the following code:

```
test.tokens.dfm <- dfm_select(test.tokens.dfm, 
                              features = train.tokens.dfm)
```

None of these work. I get an error like:

> "Error: dfm cannot be used as pattern; use 'dfm_match' instead".

I tried to use `dfm_match` function instead, but it gives a huge dfm, or something with 0 features, which cannot be aligned with the train data.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this.

Here is the full script of the tutorial: https://github.com/datasciencedojo/IntroToTextAnalyticsWithR/blob/master/IntroToTextAnalytics_Part12.R

Comment: Quanteda has gone through 2 major version updates since then, v2 & v3, change that directly affects you at the moment is documented here - https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/blob/master/NEWS.md#removals-1 . I'm afraid your question doesn't really describe how you used `dfm_match()` . Like `dfm_match(test.tokens.dfm, featnames(train.tokens.dfm))` , as guided in https://quanteda.io/reference/dfm_match.html examples?